# MBProgressHUD not stopping

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

Here's my code

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading..";
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
{
    [self information];
    [hud hide:YES];
});
```

I know that method information finishes after a while. But even after it is finished the progress bar is not moving away. What could be the reason?

Comment: try to call the `[hud hide:YES];` on main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:` method

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? I am a newbie.

Comment: So you get the proper answer now try to use that one it is perfectly fine for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading..";
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
{
[self information];
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
[hud hide:YES];
});
});
```

Comment: Works out well!! Can you explain me what did we exactly do there??

Comment: You were hiding the HUD in dispatch_async and that my friend is not the main thread. You can use dispath_sync or performSelectorOnMainThread. Remember any UI updation should be done in main thread and main thread alone.